# Add a domain to an Azure web site via code

Tags: .net, sdk, azure-web-app-service

How do I programmatically add an additional domain name to an Azure Web Site?

Hopefully there .NET API for this that I missed, perhaps in the Azure SDK or a NuGet package. Or perhaps there is a REST interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Azure Web Sites Management REST API should provide the functionality you are looking for.

The property **Site.HostNames** property of Windows Azure Web Site can be used to provide additional domain names. The properties can be provided during creation of a web site or when updating.

Please also take note of the general info on [Configuring a custom domain name for a Windows Azure web site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/). You would also have to programmatically add the verification entry to your DNS.

I am not sure if there are any wrapper SDKs/libs/powershell commandlets for the web sites management API.

Comment: The broken dokumentation URLs are a very unfortunate situation. What exactly are you trying to do @AnnArbor87? You could have a look at the xplat cli tools (e.g. https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/blob/dev/lib/commands/asm/site.domain._js ) which seem to support such operations via Azure Resource Manager. That probably implies that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790568.aspx might provide the required (now generic) operations.

Comment: I posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789231/azure-update-resource-property-with-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using either the (Azure Management) Services API, the Resources API, or the Azure RM PowerShell cmdlets.

I find using the Services API easiest, because of bugs with logging in with Microsoft accounts with PowerShell, and the absurd requirement of needing to create an Azure RM app as a GlobalAdmin in order to use the Resources API.

**PowerShell**

```
Login-AzureRmAccount  # Non-automatable because pops up OAuth window. -Credentials parameter is broken.
Set-AzureRmWebapp -Name 'SiteName' -ResourceGroupName 'ResourceGroup' -HostNames @('SiteName.azurewebsites.net', ...)
```

**Services REST API**

*Requires Client Certificate in request. Generate/download new certificates [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301775)*

```
PUT https://management.core.windows.net:8443/{subscriptionId}/services/webspaces/{webspace}/sites/{siteName}
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
x-ms-version: 2015-04-01

{
    HostNames: ['siteName.azurewebsites.net',...]
}
```

**Resources REST API**

*Requires Global Administrator account (Co-Admin does not work). Follow instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/) for setup*

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/resourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<siteName>?api-version=2015-04-01
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    HostNames: ['siteName.azurewebsites.net',...]
}
```

Comment: For the powershell command at least you should only include the custom domains and not the azurewebsites.net value, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830895/setting-host-names-for-azure-websites-via-azure-powershell,