# Add many domains to an azure web site

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I'm migrating a pretty serious multi-tenant application to Azure, and one of the challenges I see coming is that it hosts over a hundred domains.

On the Azure side, the only way I see to add a custom domain is hand-entering them via the portal. I would really like to script this out with Azure PowerShell or (perhaps less desirable for this one-off operation) one of the .Net APIs.

I did find this, which shows that it can be done with one of the REST APIs: [Add a domain to an Azure web site via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730806/add-a-domain-to-an-azure-web-site-via-code)

Is there anything for PowerShell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use -

```
Set-AzureWebsite -Name "ramisample" -HostNames @('www.abc.com', 'abc.com')
```

Make sure you point the CNAME records before adding them as domains.

Comment: Nice!... Wow I spent hours last night solving this with the REST API, this would have been so much easier. Quick question for the kids at home: I'm guessing if you have a hostname or two set up already, you better include them in your list or they will be lost. That's how the REST API works.

Comment: Strange... I can use the Set-AzureWebsite cmdlet to set properties such as -PhpVersion and -AppSettings, but trying to set HostNames does not work. It doesn't report failure, it just doesn't make the setting. I can manually set the same domains in the management portal just fine.

Comment: Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830895/setting-host-names-for-azure-websites-via-azure-powershell

Comment: How can you accomplish this with azurerm?