# Allowing Users to Enter a Custom cname on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a multi-site application running on Azure Websites. When a user signs up, they pick a name for their application and they end up with "appname.coolapplication.com". Everything so far is working great within our own domain.

Our application needs to allow users to enter their own custom domain. For example, they want to view their application from "elsewhere.com" rather than "appname.coolapplication.com". How do I go about configuring Azure Websites to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Per [these instructions](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name) you instruct the customer to enter a `CNAME` record on their domain registrar for the Azure domain, and then it begins to work.

**EDIT:**

The `CNAME` only "just works" for Azure Cloud Apps. For Azure Websites, it turns out you must add the domain in the portal as well. I'd thus recommend switching your Azure Websites to Azure Cloud Apps to simplify the issue.

Comment: But the customer's domain has to be entered in the Azure portal, no? If i just enter the CNAME record on my domain registrar, I get a 404. When I enter that domain in the Azure portal, everything works. I cannot add an entry through the Azure portal every time a customer wants to use their own domain.

Comment: Ahh yes, you have to do that for Azure Websites. I use Azure Cloud Apps for a few reasons, and you don't have to do that there. Perhaps switch to Cloud Apps so you can just CNAME without the portal part? Or create some code that uses Azure API to add the domain for the customer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell api to add custom hostnames.

See this question for details: [Add many domains to an azure web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036060/add-many-domains-to-an-azure-web-site)