# Azure - Update Resource Property with REST API

Tags: c#, json, api, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm using the REST API to create resources (WebApp + MySQL) with a template.
It works fine.
I want now to modify the hostnames and add one but I just receive a Bad Request (400) response.

The URL I refer to is:

```
"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<myResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<instanceName>?api-version=2015-08-01"
```

I'm doing a PUT, and sending the following JSON object.

```
{
  "properties": {
  "HostNames":"instanceName.azurewebsites.net, newHostName.com"
  }
}
```

It is possible that my JSON is wrong, but I tried many formats and no one works.
I tried also referring to another URL:

```
"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<myResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<instanceName>/config/web?api-version=2015-08-01"
```

And the response is OK (200) but then I check the resource with powershell and my HostNames property didn't change.

I also tried to set the HostNames with my template upon deployment but by default Azure does not allow you to add custom hostnames.

Anyone faced this before?

Comment: Not sure but a couple thoughts - can you make the change with PowerShell (Set-AzureResource)?  Then use fiddler to see the JSON body.  Does POST or PATCH make any difference?

Comment: @bmoore-msft How can I run the PowerShell cmdlets with Fiddler when all requests need client certificates?

Comment: You can install the client certs - in this case, now I would just use the -Debug switch on the PowerShell cmdlets.  Also check to make sure you're using a hosting plan that supports custom hostnames.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I used Fiddler to see the URL and body(JSON) of the Azure Powershell commands. I cant specifically tell you because I don't own/have that project anymore sorry.